# Why grub-reboot stays at the boot-once system?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I have two Linux systems installed on one machine. They share one /boot partition and are pretty much the same. From one system (A), I use grub-reboot to boot to the other system (B), or vice-versa. This is done well. But the problem is, the next boot does not return back. So it is like: A --> grub-reboot, reboot --> B --> reboot --> B...  And staring from B is the same situation.

So what could go wrong, how to debug it?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some searching, I found the problem is due to the underlying software RAID that I am using. Grub2 does not work well with this type of RAID with bug reported.